# ¿Cómo copiar el registro de usuarios de Laravel a un controlador propio?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando Laravel 5.5. He ejecutado el comando que generar el login, registro, recuperar contraseña, etc.

Por otro lado, he creado el controlador `UserController` con las funcionalidades de index(), show(), destroy(), etc.

***Nota:*** He creado este controlador, ya que quiero gestionar los usuarios, es decir, tener un listado y poder verlos, editarlos, eliminarlos o crear nuevos.

Luego, he copiado el fichero `resources/view/auth/register.blade.php` a `resources/view/users/create.blade.php`. El problema es que, no puedo integrar la funcionalidad de registro de usuarios, ya que los métodos se llaman distintos, o en ciertos casos se llaman igual pero el comportamiento es diferente.

Yo quiero que mi create() retorne la vista y el store() lo guarde, no obstante, en el controlador del registro de usuario, utiliza create() para guardar y showForm... para mostrar el formulario, además al estar utilizando el trait `RegistersUsers` obliga a que se llame a register (en vez de a store()).

Hace horas estoy intentando hacerlo funcionar y no hay caso. Se me ocurre que mi controlador, UserControler, carezca de las funciones create y store, y simplemente usar el registro por defecto de laravel, no obstante, eso tendría un problema ya que no podría crear el modificar usuarios.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: Si eh entendido bien, dices que el problema para ti es que crees que al usar tu propio controlador(UserController) no podras insertar ni modificar los usuarios que registras en la DB mediante el controlador Auth de laravel?

Comment: no, quizás me expresé mal. Lo que quiero es "mover" todo lo que tenga que ver con el registro de usuarios generado por Laravel a mi controlador

Comment: Podrías compartir cual es la razon por la que quieres "mover" todo eso? Es decir, cuando generas los auth controllers le dices a laravel que se encargue de implementar la autenticacion de tu aplicación. Estos controladores son altamente personalizables, puedes hacer casi cualquier cosa desde ellos, no deberías tener ningun problema si decides agregar código propio en ellos.

Comment: si entiendo bien, tendrías que cambiar la ruta del formulario en blade (resources/view/users/create.blade.php) para que apunte al controlador/metodo que creaste (UserController@store)

Answer (score 0):

Como consejo, no edites cosas que ya vienen hechas y funcionan perfecto.

Los usuarios creados mediante laravel puedes gestionarlos 100%, siempre y cuando tu modelo de `Users` funcione perfecto.

```
User:get();

User::find(valor);
```

De lo contrario si aun siguen con ganas de editar todo, puedes copiar los controladores usados para login y crear tus propias rutas, pero luego debes editar todas las vistas con estas rutas nuevas y llamados nuevos